# Linux kernel BUG() call does not hang the kernel

Tags: kernel, smp

I am running an old version of the linux code(2.6.27). I have the  CONFIG_BUG=y and also the HAVE_ARCH_BUG defined. So i am using the BUG() definition in the asm-x86/bug.h instead of asm-generic.
I see that when i insmod a test module (which just has a BUG() call), it does not crash the box. I am able to get to the console. It is an SMP system so i would expect that. 
The question i have is , by design, was BUG() supposed to hang the box just like panic? If so, any reason why it is not on this kernel?

thx
Murali

Comment: This is x86, correct?

Comment: Yes it is x86 32 bit system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BUG()` itself is not supposed to hang the box, so the behaviour of your system is OK.

On x86, `BUG()` eventually tries to execute `ud2` machine instruction which leads to "Invalid opcode" exception. It is up to the kernel how to handle that, whether to output a message and continue working or to stop. Different kernels may react in different ways here.

Comment: Thx , i see it now. BUG was calling ud2 which invoked die. and unless there is panic_on_oops, or in interrupt context, it just returns exits with signal passed(SIGSEGV) in this case.